# How do I copy between disks without having to wait to click on the error boxes?

Tags: copy

I want to copy from one external hard disk to another. The content to copy is around 1 TB. Is there a way I can do this without sitting in front of the computer? The issue is that there are errors while copying and I have to click on boxes so that the transfer can continue. This prevents me from doing other things and I have to sit in front of the computer. I hope I am clear and you can help me.

Regards.

Edit: Just now, I am using rsync to copy the disks.

```
rsync -av '/media/kartikeys/My Passport/' '/media/kartikeys/MONK/My Passport/'
```

Earlier, I was copying and pasting as I usually do. The errors I'd get were about Duplicate Files, and about some file not being found. I would come back to the computer to find that unless I click the 'skip' button, for example, the copying stops.

Comment: Which errors do you get? Which tool(s) did you try which acted against your expectations? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: command line, "rsync".

Comment: @Rinzwind Is that an answer to dessert's question or a suggestion what tool to use?

Comment: @PerlDuck how would I know what katya used? :+)

Comment: @Rinzwind just now because of an error, one of the external hard disks had to be plugged in again. Do I have to start rsync from scratch or will it automatically carry on?

Comment: @dessert am I clear? Kindly let me know if the edited information is okay.

Comment: You might want to add some options `-P` for "The -P option is equivalent to --partial --progress.   Its  pur-
         pose  is to make it much easier to specify these two options for
         a long transfer that may be interrupted."

Comment: @rinzwind the rsync transfer stopped. I was about to paste the error here but I had to restart the laptop and can't do it now. Is there a way I can use rsync to copy without giving me dialogue boxes (if it does so) and with the ability to continue from partial copying? I just want to leave laptop on for hours and come back to it in the end.

Comment: I am now using rsync -av -partial '/media/kartikeys/My Passport/' '/media/kartikeys/MONK/My Passport/' 

Is this okay?

Comment: `rsync` is a command line tool, there are no dialogue boxes with it, and IIRC it *does* continue to copy the data in the case of errors. Do you know the `-q` flag to suppress non-error messages?

Comment: @dessert I don't know about -q. Just learned about partial. SHould I stop and restart with -q too now? Can you help formulate a code? And do I need -progress too? edit: just learned -progress shows the transfer progress. How do i redo without losing what i have copied till now?

Comment: Is it possible you’re actually using `grsync`?

Comment: I am using rsync. I typed grsync in google. It seems to have an interface. Do you recommend I stop copying with rync and use grsync instead? Will I lose what I have copied till now?

Comment: I am continuing to use rsync. This copying should take many many hours. I will need to interrupt and restart. I hope I can just type this command: rsync -av -partial -progress - q '/media/kartikeys/My Passport/' '/media/kartikeys/MONK/My Passport/'.             Thanks in advance. Do let me know.